# Assets Images not rendering in flutter-ios. How to render local asset-images inside html <img src...> tag in flutter without using webview?

Tags: html, image, flutter, assets, dart-html

[Open issue at GitHub](https://github.com/Afur/flutter_html_to_pdf/issues/18)

I am using HTML/CSS to create PDF views. So, In some cases we need render images from the local asset-folder. When we try to render the file from assets folder image is not displaying. How to resolve this issue?

**iOS-Screenshot:**

[image]

**Full Source Code:**

*RenderHtml.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_full_pdf_viewer/flutter_full_pdf_viewer.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html_to_pdf/flutter_html_to_pdf.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

var base64Image = "";

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String generatedPdfFilePath;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    generateExampleDocument();
  }

  Future<void> generateExampleDocument() async {
    var htmlContent = """
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
          <style>
          table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
          }
          th, td, p {
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: left;
          }
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h2>PDF Generated with flutter_html_to_pdf plugin</h2>

          <table style="width:100%">
            <caption>Sample HTML Table</caption>
            <tr>
              <th>Month</th>
              <th>Savings</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>January</td>
              <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>February</td>
              <td>50</td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <p>Image loaded from web</p>
          <img src="file:///storage/example/your_sample_image.png" alt="web-img">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wxaJsXF.png" alt="web-img">
          <img src="file:///assets/profyl.jpg" alt="asset-img">
          <img src="assets/profyl.jpg" alt="asset-img">
          <img src="file:///storage/assets/profyl.png" alt="storage-img">
          <img src="file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/profyl.jpg" alt="android_asset-img">
          <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
      AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
          9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Base64 Image" style="height: 90%;" />
        </body>
      </html>
      """;

    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var targetPath = appDocDir.path;
    var targetFileName = "example-pdf";

    var generatedPdfFile = await FlutterHtmlToPdf.convertFromHtmlContent(
        htmlContent, targetPath, targetFileName);
    generatedPdfFilePath = generatedPdfFile.path;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Open Generated PDF Preview"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => PDFViewerScaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Generated PDF Document")),
                    path: generatedPdfFilePath)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
  flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.4
  flutter_html_to_pdf: ^0.5.2
  printing: ^2.1.7
  path_provider: ^1.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally use http://fluttericon.com to generate my own font file which can include icons from many major libraries like "Font Awesome" or others. With that tool you can download a ttf file (and also a config file which you can use to further work on your project at the mentioned page). You will also get a dart file for easy referencing your icons.

This ttf file should be put somewhere in your assets folder or in a subfolder. Then in pubspec just do:

```
  fonts:
    - family:  MyFont
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/MyFont.ttf
```

Put the generated dart file with the icons constants somewhere in your project. Lets call it myfont_icons.dart. It should look like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class MyFont {
  MyFont._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'MyFont';

  static const IconData people = const IconData(0xe802, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData th_list = const IconData(0xe803, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
}
```

So its basically the same thing you will have with in Web development with a CSS stylesheet where all the icons are defined with css classes.

When using the icons in your classes, just import that dart file and use it like so:

```
Icon(
  MyFont.people,
  size: 94,
),
```

Comment: I want to use the icons via HTML, css in order to render the icons in PDF. So, This is only option for widget case. There is already font-awesome plugin to use via widget. I want to use that fonts in HTML. Please check the question carefully. Please reply back if you didn't get the question

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the assets folder in pubspec.yaml directly inside the flutter like this

```
flutter:
 assets:
  - assets/profyl.png
```

or

```
 flutter:
  assets:
  - assets
```

for adding whole assets folder

Update:

As I have pointed out your pathnames in HTML are not correct.
I have tried various pathnames below :

```
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wxaJsXF.png" alt="web-img1">
      <img src="file:/Users/Faisal/Projects/Flutter_Apps/flutter_app/assets/f.png" alt="web-img2">
      <img src="file:///Users/Faisal/Projects/Flutter_Apps/flutter_app/assets/f.png" alt="web-img3">
      <img src="file:f.png" alt="web-img4">
      <img src="file:///storage/assets/f.png" alt="img5">
      <img src="file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/f.png" alt="web-img6">
      <img src="/Users/Faisal/Projects/Flutter_Apps/flutter_app/assets/f.png" alt="web-img6">
```

as you can see in the image 3 pathnames are working locally whereas 3 are not.

[Screenshot from apple simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGcRO.png)

Comment: Yeah, Off course. This issue is only in iOS so there is some other issue.

Comment: Your path of images are not correct. The apple logo that you are able to generate is from web. All the local ones don't have correct path name.

Comment: You cannot give the direct path of the asset when you try to render the views using HTML. Please try that out.

Comment: Hello Faisal, How do we know the user main directory name? /Users/???/??/Flutter_Apps/flutter_app/..

Comment: If you or on mac just copy the pathname of asset. You can do so by right click and hold option key, then copy will change to copy as pathname.

Comment: We have to make this path dynamic. This code will be used in iOS app.

Comment: Any updates on how can we use this local path in iOS-App?