# Font Awesome icons are not rendering when trying to convert HTML to PDF in flutter app (Android platform)

Tags: android, flutter, pdf, font-awesome, dart-html

In android platform, When I try to generate the PDF using HTML content FontAwesome icon is not rendering as expected. It only renders sometime like 2/10 times. Can you please help me with this issue?

Code: Using [dart_pdf and printing package](https://pub.dev/packages/printing)

```
await Printing.layoutPdf(
onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => await Printing.convertHtml(
  format: format,
  html: '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <title>Demystifying Email Design</title> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> </head> <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"> <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> <tr> <td style="padding: 10px 0 30px 0;"> <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc; border-collapse: collapse;"> <tr> <td align="center" bgcolor="#ee4c50" style="padding: 40px 0 30px 0; color: #153643; font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"> Design Researcher<p> <table align="left" style="width:100%; font-size: 8px; padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;"> <tr> <td><i class="fa fa-info" style="font-size:20px;color:white;"></i></td> <td style="color: white; font-size: 14px;">Will Smith</td> </tr> <tr> <td><i class="fa fa-reply" style="font-size:20px;color:white;"></i></td> <td style="color: white; font-size: 14px;">will.smith@gmail.com</td> </tr> <tr> <td><i class="fa fa-phone" style="font-size:20px;color:white;"></i></td> <td style="color: white; font-size: 14px;">+11 72836472634 </td> </tr> <tr> <td><i class="fa fa-map" style="font-size:20px;color:white;"></i></td> <td style="color: white; font-size: 14px;">Minnisote, US</td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> <tr> <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;"> <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> <tr> <td style="color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px;"> <b>Barak Obama</b> </td> </tr> <tr> <td style="padding: 20px 0 30px 0; color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;"> <p> <p>Jul 21, 2020</p> <p>HR Manager<br>Mobotechnology Inc.<br>Jawlakhel, Lalitpur<br>hr@mobotechnology.com</p> I’m writing to resign my position as customer service representative, effective June 15, 2020. I’ve recently decided to go back to school, and my program starts in early September. I’m tendering my resignation now so that I can be as helpful as possible to you during the transition. I’ve truly enjoyed my time working with you and everyone else on our team at LMK. It’s rare to find a customer service role that offers as much opportunity to grow and learn and such a positive, inspiring team of people to grow and learn with. </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> <tr> <td bgcolor="#ee4c50" style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;"> <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> <tr> <td style="color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;" width="75%"> ® Someone, somewhere 2013<br /> <a href="#" style="color: #ffffff;"> <font color="#ffffff">Unsubscribe</font> </a> to this newsletter instantly </td> <td align="right" width="25%"> <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> <tr> <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;"> <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" style="color: #ffffff;"> <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/tw.gif" alt="Twitter" width="38" height="38" style="display: block;" border="0" /> </a> </td> <td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;" width="20"> </td> <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;"> <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" style="color: #ffffff;"> <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/fb.gif" alt="Facebook" width="38" height="38" style="display: block;" border="0" /> </a> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </body> </html>',
));
```

**Output:**

Note, in figure-1 the FontAwesome icons renders but it figure-2 the fa-icons are not rendering. It only renders sometime like 2/10 times.

[image][image]

*Note: It might sounds wired, but we use Image tag like below,the FA-Icons renders as expected but without Image tag it won't render as expected in Android platform.*

```
<img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="Airplane" />
```

Comment: For starters I'd move all remote css to the phone storage, 1) The user doesn't have to download those files over and over again, 2) It isn't prone to network errors (data connection isn't that reliable).  So `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` shouldn't be pointing to the web, but somewhere locally.

Comment: When we put css file locally, flutter-android works. But it do not work in flutter - iOS? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57956232/assets-images-not-rendering-in-flutter-ios-how-to-render-local-asset-images-ins